# What is the time complexity of the following equation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

I'm having a few problems working out the time complexity using Big-O notation.

This is the equation:
`88n^2 logn + 81 + 3n^3 + 12n`

I can figure it out I'm guessing its something like:
`O(n^2 logn)` or `O(n^3)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: O(n^3). It is the largest tag.

Comment: i thought this i just needed a second opinion, thanks so much :)

Comment: An equation doesn't have a time complexity (nor a space complexity). An algorithm does.

Comment: are you asking the time complexity of calculating that equation? If `n` is given, the time complexity will be `O(1)`.

Comment: For an equation, there is a notable lack of equality signs. A function can be dominated by another, but does not have a time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know `n` grow faster than `logn`.

You also know we can multiply same  strength factor to a complexity equation.

So we could simply say `n^3` grow faster than `n^2 logn`.

=> `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 0):

Since growth rate of **n** greater than the growth rate of **log(n)**,

we can say **n^3** grow faster than **n^2 log(n)**.

So 88n^2 logn + 81 + 3n^3 + 12n => **O(n^3)**